# KTDatatables want to change page length options

Tags: datatable, datatables

I am using keentheme's Metronic admin template. It has KTDatatables. I can see page length options now as:
5, 10, 30, 50, 100

I want to change it to, to show all records:
5, 10, 30, 50, 100, All

My datatable code:

```
    var datatable = $("#attendance_datatable").KTDatatable({

      data: {
        type: "remote",
        source: baseUrl + "/Hrms/AttendanceManagement/getEmployeesAttendance/",
        pageSize: 10,
      },
      layout: {
        scroll: true, 
        footer: false, 
      },

      sortable: true,
      pagination: true,
      lengthMenu: [
        [10, 25, 50, -1],
        [10, 25, 50, "All"],
      ],

      search: {
        input: $("#attendance_datatable_search_query"),
        key: "generalSearch",
      },

      columns: [
        {
          field: "emp_name",
          title: "Employee Name",
          width: 120,
        },
        {
          field: "attendance_date",
          title: "Date",
          width: 85,
        },
      ],
    });
  };
```

I have tried following:
https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html

Answer (score 0):

Change `lengthMenu` option

```js
      lengthMenu: [
        [5, 10, 30, 50, 100, -1],
        [5, 10, 30, 50, 100, "All"],
      ],
```

This should work

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have already apply this, not working

Comment: what error you r getting?

Comment: Not getting any error, this code is doing nothing

Answer (score 0):

I edited as below and it worked code.
You changes "lengthMenu" -> toolbar needs to be added, changes it as follows to chage the pagination.

```
 toolbar: {
    // toolbar placement can be at top or bottom or both top and bottom repeated
    placement: ['bottom'],
    
    // toolbar items
    items: {
    // pagination
    pagination: {
    // page size select
    pageSizeSelect: [5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 999], // display dropdown to select pagination size. -1 is used for "ALl" option
    },
    }
}
```